# Convert Corel Draw to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-conversion, coreldraw

I have a team of 5 requesting to purchase Corel Draw just to be able to convert Corel Draw File to Illustrator files.

Is there a way to convert Corel Draw files to illustrator without having to purchase Corel Draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UniConvertor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) can convert Corel Draw (.cdr) files to Adobe Illustrator files (.ai).

Comment: I don't have enough rep points to up vote your answer but if I did I would up vote it twice.  :) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You can accept the answer.  That gives me 15 rep and you 2. :)  Hit the little check mark next to the post.